# Numeric value out of range for a DOUBLE(5,5)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Im getting Numeric value out of range `Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'Value' at row 1`

When im trying to do

```
$GetLatId = $PDO -> prepare("INSERT INTO `longitude` (`Value`) VAlUE(:Val);");
$GetLatId -> bindValue(':Val',12345.12345);
try{
    $GetLatId -> execute();
}catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

`Value` field is `DOUBLE(5,5)`

Can this be mysql configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation, you see That Double 5,5 means, that you have defined the Maximum Digits to 5 and this 5 are after the decimal Point.

[Official Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html):

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.

What you need to store your value is Double (10,5)

Comment: omg,..
 I did read the doc multiples times but didnt understand it like that.  THANKS! ( even though this question might sound really stupid now... ) lol